# TopMost window constant refresh

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a bit of an issue. I have two applications that run simultaneously where both have TopMost window properties set to TRUE.

1. Application A - A full-screen application with TopMost window
   properties set to TRUE.

   - I have no access to the hard-code data, I can not change this
     application. This application CANNOT be minimized as it is always to be displayed.
2. Application B - A static smaller window that needs to constantly stay ON-TOP of Application A.

   - This is my application, I have TopMost properties set to TRUE, however, whenever I click on the full-screen application(A) it hides application(B). They both have TopMost properties set to TRUE. With these apps utilizing the same window property settings they act as regular windows (You focus on one, it will overlap the other).

I am trying to find a solution to constantly refresh the focus on Application(B) so it will remain on top, my application is utilizing a countdown banner that should constantly lay ontop of Application(A):

```
Public Class RebootWarning



Dim t As TimeSpan

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TopMost = True
    t = New TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick


    t -= New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
    Label1.Text = t.ToString.Substring(3)
    If t = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0) Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        'MsgBox("Time out")
        Process.Start("CMD")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: As was explained the first time you asked this question, this is the expected behavior, two (or more) topmost windows will simply swap with each other.  [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413) explains why. If you search with keywords like "staying on top of topmost" you can find various attempts at workarounds (timers, activate events, hooking WindProc, etc) but those all have different inadequacies as a solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of it being expected behavior with two windows utilizing the same properties. I'll keep searching for ideas with the keywords you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution!
 I ended up adding and enabling an additional timer that loops, which then repeatedly requests focus when the timer is complete.

```
 Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.Focus()
    Me.TopMost = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So you're pretty much not going to allow the other app to accept user input and activity (you are stealing focus away from the other app constantly)? If this is a 'countdown banner', that would imply that the user needs to accomplish some action in the other app before the countdown expires, but you're not going to allow them to do that (at least not in a friendly way)? Not what I would regard as a 'solution', but not my business, right?

Comment: So, this application lives wihtin a touch screen system, not a standard desktop. There are heavy limitations as to what can be accomplished on the screen. I was worried about the same situation that you're referencing, however, this does not interfere with actions on the application below it. It's a crude solution, but it works in my situation.